# Unable to Connect to Xirsys STUN and TURN servers using EasyRTC

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, easyrtc, xirsys

I'm working on a video chat application using EasyRTC and Xirsys. It works fine on its own (using the Google STUN server), but fails when I create a listener for the getIceConfig event. The EasyRTC server is on port 8080, and I also have an Apache server running on port 80. I've set up my server.js file as follows:

```
// Load required modules
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("../");           // EasyRTC external module

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called "static" to be the web root.
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

// Start Express http server on port 8080
var webServer = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(8080);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});

easyrtc.setOption("logLevel", "debug");

// Overriding the default easyrtcAuth listener, only so we can directly access its callback
easyrtc.events.on("easyrtcAuth", function(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, callback) {
    easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.easyrtcAuth(socket, easyrtcid, msg, socketCallback, function(err, connectionObj){
        if (err || !msg.msgData || !msg.msgData.credential || !connectionObj) {
            callback(err, connectionObj);
            return;
        }

        connectionObj.setField("credential", msg.msgData.credential, {"isShared":false});

        console.log("["+easyrtcid+"] Credential saved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));

        callback(err, connectionObj);
    });
});

// To test, lets print the credential to the console for every room join!
easyrtc.events.on("roomJoin", function(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback) {
    console.log("["+connectionObj.getEasyrtcid()+"] Credential retrieved!", connectionObj.getFieldValueSync("credential"));
    easyrtc.events.defaultListeners.roomJoin(connectionObj, roomName, roomParameter, callback);
});


// Start EasyRTC server
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer, null, function(err, rtcRef) {
    console.log("Initiated");

    rtcRef.events.on("roomCreate", function(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback) {
        console.log("roomCreate fired! Trying to create: " + roomName);

        appObj.events.defaultListeners.roomCreate(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback);
    });
});

easyrtc.on("getIceConfig", function(connectionObj, callback) {

    // This object will take in an array of XirSys STUN and TURN servers
    var iceConfig = [];

    request({ 
        url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
        qs: {
            ident: "***",
            secret: "***",
            domain: "***",
            application: "default",
            room: "default",
            secure: 1
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                // body.d.iceServers is where the array of ICE servers lives
                iceConfig = body.d.iceServers;  
                console.log(iceConfig);
                callback(null, iceConfig);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The debugging error messages are below:

```
info    - EasyRTC: Starting EasyRTC Server (v1.0.15) on Node (v4.4.5)
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting event 'startup'
debug   - EasyRTC: Running func 'onStartup'
debug   - EasyRTC: Configuring Http server
debug   - EasyRTC: Setting up demos to be accessed from '/demos/'
debug   - EasyRTC: Setting up API files to be accessed from '/easyrtc/'
debug   - EasyRTC: Configuring Socket server
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating application: 'default'
debug   - EasyRTC: [default] Room [default] Running func 'onRoomCreate'
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating room: 'default' with options: {}
info    - EasyRTC: EasyRTC Server Ready For Connections (v1.0.15)
Initiated
debug   - EasyRTC: [U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Socket connected
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting event 'connection'
debug   - EasyRTC: Running func 'onConnection'
debug   - EasyRTC: [U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Running func 'onEasyrtcAuth'
debug   - EasyRTC: Attempt to request non-existent application name: 'easyrtc.audioVideoSimple'
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting Authenticate
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating application: 'easyrtc.audioVideoSimple'
roomCreate fired! Trying to create: default
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple] Room [default] Running func 'onRoomCreate'
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating room: 'default' with options: {}
[U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Credential retrieved! null
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Running func 'onRoomJoin'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.emitRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.generateRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][U0LMzF8jbIBdxq3sGtxP] Running func 'onSendToken'
C:\Users\Jamie\nodes\easyrtc\node_modules\easyrtc\server_example\server.js:58
    request({
    ^

ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jamie\nodes\easyrtc\node_modules\easyrtc\server_example\server.js:58:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at C:\Users\Jamie\nodes\easyrtc\node_modules\easyrtc\lib\easyrtc_default_event_listeners.js:1057:34
    at fn (C:\Users\Jamie\nodes\easyrtc\node_modules\easyrtc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:582:34)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\Jamie\nodes\easyrtc\node_modules\easyrtc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:498:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

info    - EasyRTC: Starting EasyRTC Server (v1.0.15) on Node (v4.4.5)
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting event 'startup'
debug   - EasyRTC: Running func 'onStartup'
debug   - EasyRTC: Configuring Http server
debug   - EasyRTC: Setting up demos to be accessed from '/demos/'
debug   - EasyRTC: Setting up API files to be accessed from '/easyrtc/'
debug   - EasyRTC: Configuring Socket server
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating application: 'default'
debug   - EasyRTC: [default] Room [default] Running func 'onRoomCreate'
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating room: 'default' with options: {}
info    - EasyRTC: EasyRTC Server Ready For Connections (v1.0.15)
Initiated
debug   - EasyRTC: [YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Socket connected
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting event 'connection'
debug   - EasyRTC: Running func 'onConnection'
debug   - EasyRTC: [YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Running func 'onEasyrtcAuth'
debug   - EasyRTC: Attempt to request non-existent application name: 'easyrtc.audioVideoSimple'
debug   - EasyRTC: Emitting Authenticate
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating application: 'easyrtc.audioVideoSimple'
roomCreate fired! Trying to create: default
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple] Room [default] Running func 'onRoomCreate'
debug   - EasyRTC: Creating room: 'default' with options: {}
[YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Credential retrieved! null
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Running func 'onRoomJoin'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.emitRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Room [default] Running func 'connectionRoomObj.generateRoomDataDelta'
debug   - EasyRTC: [easyrtc.audioVideoSimple][YBCNOMSW7zbRXF0IH_g2] Running func 'onSendToken'
[...path]\node_modules\easyrtc\server_example\server.js:58
    request({
    ^

ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> ([...path]\node_modules\easyrtc\server_example\server.js:58:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at [...path]\node_modules\easyrtc\lib\easyrtc_default_event_listeners.js:1057:34
    at fn (C[...path]\node_modules\easyrtc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:582:34)
    at Immediate._onImmediate ([...path]\node_modules\easyrtc\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:498:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Any ideas about what is causing this? It happens in both chrome and firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
ReferenceError: request is not defined
```

You forgot to invoke `request` with the http object.

Here's your fix:

Change this:

```
request({ 
        url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
        ...
```

To be this:

```
http.request({ 
        url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/ice',
        ...
```

Comment: This seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Cool.  So give me a green checkbox (i.e. accept the answer).